# Getting player position, cannot pass object instance over due to include loop

Tags: c++, sfml

I am currently working on a clone of Space Invaders in C++ and SFML and seem to be having a problem with the players position.

Currently, when the invaders shoot, the hit-box of the player continues to be the start position of the player recorded as 900, 500. This hit-box does not move the player. I am unsure of why and how to fix it. I know I cannot include game.h into invaders.h as game.h includes invaders.h hence causing an include loop. I need to take the player instance that is created in game.h, and pass that on to invaders.h for the hit-box of the player ton be passed along as well.

This is the code that relates to the invaders shots and the players position.

Game.h

```
#include "Player.h"
#include "invaders.h"
class Game
{
private:
Player* player;
vector<Invaders*> vInvaders;
public:
void updateInputs();
};
```

Game.cpp

```
#include "Game.h"
void Game::updateInputs()
{
    //Updates player movement.
    player->updateInputs();

    //Creating bullets.
    if ((Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Space)) && (this->player->bCanAttack()))
    {
        this->vBullets.push_back(new Bullet(this->textures["BULLET"], this->player->getPos().x, this->player->getPos().y, 0.f, -1.f, 5.f));
        SoundEngine::playShot();
    }
//Move player.
    if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Left))
    {
        move(-1.f, 0);
        getBounds();
        //cout << player->getBounds().left << " " << player->getBounds().top << endl;
    }
    if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Right))
    {
        move(1.f, 0);
        getBounds();
        //cout << player->getBounds().left << " " << player->getBounds().top << endl;
    }
}
```

Player.h

```
class Player
{
public:
const FloatRect getBounds() const;
void move(const float kfDirX, const float kfDirY);
};
```

Player.cpp

```
#include "Player.h"
const FloatRect Player::getBounds() const
{
    return this->sprite.getGlobalBounds(); //Returns the bounding box of player.
}

void Player::move(const float kfDirX, const float kfDirY)
{
    this->sprite.move(this->fSpeed * kfDirX, 0); //Moves player across screen.
}
```

Invaders.h

```
#include "Player.h" //It is not needed, but doesn't work without it.
class Invaders
{
private:
Player player; //It is not needed, but does't work without it. Need the instance from Game.h, don't need to make a new instance here.
public:
void updateBullets();
};
```

Invaders.cpp

```
#include "Invaders.h"
void Invaders::updateBullets()
{
    unsigned int iCounter = 0;
    for (auto* invaderBullet : this->vInvaderBullets)
    {
        invaderBullet->update();

        for (size_t k = 0; k < this->vInvaderBullets.size(); k++)
        {
            //THIS DOES NOT WORK!!!!
            if (this->vInvaderBullets[k]->getBounds().intersects(player.getBounds()))
            {
                cout << player.getBounds().left << " " << player.getBounds().top << endl;
                this->vInvaderBullets.erase(this->vInvaderBullets.begin() + k);
                this->player.isDead(true);
                Variables::iLives--;
            }
            else
            {
                this->player.isDead(false);
            }
        }

        //Bullet culling at bottom of screen.
        if ((invaderBullet->getBounds().top + invaderBullet->getBounds().height) > 1100.f)
        {
            //std::cout << this->invaderBullets.size() << std::endl;
            delete this->vInvaderBullets.at(iCounter);
            this->vInvaderBullets.erase(this->vInvaderBullets.begin() + iCounter);
            iCounter--;
            //Check to see if bullets are deleted.
            //std::cout << this->invaderBullets.size() << std::endl;
        }
        iCounter++;

        for (size_t k = 0; k < this->vInvaderBullets.size(); k++)
        {
            if (this->vInvaderBullets[k]->getBounds().intersects(this->barrier.getBounds(1)))
            {
                SoundEngine::playBarrierHit();
                this->vInvaderBullets.erase(this->vInvaderBullets.begin() + k);
                this->barrier.barrierHit(1);
            }
            else if (this->vInvaderBullets[k]->getBounds().intersects(this->barrier.getBounds(2)))
            {
                SoundEngine::playBarrierHit();
                this->vInvaderBullets.erase(this->vInvaderBullets.begin() + k);
                this->barrier.barrierHit(2);
            }
            else if (this->vInvaderBullets[k]->getBounds().intersects(this->barrier.getBounds(3)))
            {
                SoundEngine::playBarrierHit();
                this->vInvaderBullets.erase(this->vInvaderBullets.begin() + k);
                this->barrier.barrierHit(3);
            }
            else if (this->vInvaderBullets[k]->getBounds().intersects(this->barrier.getBounds(4)))
            {
                SoundEngine::playBarrierHit();
                this->vInvaderBullets.erase(this->vInvaderBullets.begin() + k);
                this->barrier.barrierHit(4);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `#pragma once` in order to break the include loop?

Comment: I have, however it does nothing to resolve the loop

Comment: Your code doesn't present any include loop. Neither of the 3 headers require any other header to work, but it's quite clear they are not complete. Please provide [mcve] (`.cpp` files are probably not useful here, you can omit them)

Comment: This will be helpful in case of circular includes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-build-errors-due-to-circular-dependency-amongst-classes

Comment: I doubt that this is a circular include problem.  Those will almost always cause errors at compile time, but it's clear that you are able to compile and run the game.

Comment: I need to take the player instance that is created in game.h, and pass that on to invaders.h for the hit-box of the player ton be passed along as well. The only reason it compiles right now is cause I've created a new instance of Player in inavders.h.

Comment: Move all knowledge of the player away from `Invaders` and write the player-manipuating logic in `Game`.

Comment: @user1883616 When you asked this question before I suggested you pass the player as a parameter from the Game method (where it's defined) to the Invaders method where it's used. Did you try that? Did it not work for you? It's the obvious solution without refactoring your classes (which might well be the best solution).

Comment: Forward-declaration of the `Player`-class in Invaders.h?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting a member of type `Player` in `Invaders` means it's a separate object, and probably not the same `Player` used by `Game`. So most likely player movement happens to the `Game`'s `Player`, but the invaders are targeting their own distinct `Player` which hasn't moved.

Since `Invaders::updateBullets()` needs the `Player` object, several options are:

- Pass a `Player&` or `Game&` to the `updateBullets` function.
- Make `Game` a singleton, with a public way to get the `Game` object and therefore its `Player` object, from any context.
- Keep a `Player*` or `Game*` pointer in class `Invaders` - but if those objects could ever be destroyed before `Invaders` objects, dealing with that will be tricky. And this may be a bit "wasteful".

And in general, remember a class definition isn't needed if you're just dealing with pointers or references to that class, and this can help reduce the needed `#include` directives. For example, you could change Game.h and Game.cpp:

```
// Game.h
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H

#include <vector>

class Player;
class Invaders;

class Game
{
private:
    Player* player;
    std::vector<Invaders*> vInvaders;
public:
    void updateInputs();
};

#endif

// Game.cpp
#include "Game.h"
#include "Player.h"
#include "Invaders.h"

// ...
```